# Sacar promedio de números en un txt y que me los muestre después del Login

Tags: java

Estoy intentando sacar el promedio de unos datos que están en un `.txt`, entonces es para que me cuenten si esta bien.

Este es el código

```
public double  Lecturatxt(){

  String ruta = "C://Users//Tecgu//Desktop//datos.txt";

   Scanner archivo = null; 
    try{
       archivo = new Scanner (new File(ruta));
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
          System.err.println(e);
    }

   double  num = 0, count = 0, res = 0;

   while (archivo.hasNext()){

    num = archivo.nextDouble();
    count = (count + num)/ num;
    res = count;
 }

return res;
```

Ahora estoy tratando de mostrarlo dentro de una opción de Login después de que el Login me es verificado de otro `.txt`

Lo hice así

```
   else if (e.getSource() == ingresar){

        String d = Comparacion();
        double c = Lecturatxt();

        if (d.equals("S")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuario y Clave Válidos");
        }
        else if (d.equals("S")) {
            double  count = 0;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El promedio es : " + count);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Reintente");
        }

    }
```

Quedo atento a sus aportes.

yo necesito que después de que se valide el  login y me deje pasar  me muestre el promedio de los datos en el .txt
adjunto código de las acciones.

```
    @Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource() == borrar){

    Tuser.setText("");
    Tpass.setText("");


    }

    else if (e.getSource() == ingresar){

        String d = Comparacion();


        if (d.equals("S")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuario y Clave Válidos");
             double  count = Lecturatxt(); // Asignamos directamente
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El promedio es : " + count);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Reintente");
        }

    }

}

public String Comparacion() {
    String ruta = "C://Users//Tecgu//Desktop//Contraseña.txt";
    String msj[] = new String[2];
    String res="N";
    File archivo;
    FileReader fr = null;
    BufferedReader br;
    try {
        archivo = new File(ruta);
        fr = new FileReader(archivo);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String linea;
        int i = 0;
        while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null) {
            msj[i] = linea;
            i++;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (null != fr) {
                fr.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            System.err.println(e2);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(msj[0]+"  "+msj[1]);
    if(msj[0].equals(Tuser.getText()) 
            && 
            msj[1].equals(Tpass.getText())){
    res="S";
    }

    return res;

  }

public double  Lecturatxt(){

    String ruta = "C://Users//Tecgu//Desktop//datos.txt";
Scanner archivo = null; 
try{
   archivo = new Scanner (new File(ruta));
}
catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println(e);
}
finally {
    if (archivo != null) archivo.close();
}

 double  sum = 0;
 int i = 0;
 int count = 0;
 while (archivo.hasNext()){
   sum += archivo.nextDouble();
   i++;
 }

 return count/i;
```

}

Quedo atento

Answer (score 0):

El proceso para sacar el promedio , parece ser incorrecto , la división del total entre la cantidad debe ir fuera del ciclo , ¿Cómo saber el total de números ? , Una opción sería crear una variable `i` con valor inicial `0` y que incremente después de  leer y añadir al total *(sum)*. Además no  olvidar cerrar el flujo con `close()`

```
public double  Lecturatxt(){
    String ruta = "C://Users//Tecgu//Desktop//datos.txt";
    Scanner archivo = null; 
    try{
       archivo = new Scanner (new File(ruta));
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
          System.err.println(e);
    }
    finally {
        if (archivo != null) archivo.close();
    }

     double  sum = 0;
     int i = 0;
     while (archivo.hasNext()){
       sum += archivo.nextDouble();
       i++;
     }
     return count/i;
}
```

La parte de la validación y el `Login` , la llamada al método `Lecturatxt()` , debería ir en `else if (d.equals("S")) {` para no ejecutar el método si no se usará *(Resultado)*.

```
else if (e.getSource() == ingresar){
    String d = Comparacion();
    if (d.equals("S")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuario y Clave Válidos");
        double  count = Lecturatxt(); // Asignamos directamente
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El promedio es : " + count);
    }
   else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Reintente");
    }

}
```

> Recuerde que si emplea Java 7+ , podría recurrir a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: Mira que realizando lo que me indicaste, pero yo necesito que después de que se valide el  login y me deje pasar  me muestre el promedio de los datos en el .txt

Comment: @GustavoJimenezVera Sí el valor de retorno del método `Comparacion()` es igual a `S` , obtiene el promedio con `Lecturatxt()` y lo muestra, no me fije que tiene la comparación `2` veces. por lo demás debería funcionar.